# c# mvc nreco HtmlToPdfConverter issue converting html document to pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, html, pdf

I am using the nReco HtmlToPdfConverter class to try and convert an html document to a pdf. This works fine as is with one exception. I have javascript which is ran on document.ready and the javascript is not rendered by the time the html is converted to a pdf, resulting in my barcodes (produced by my javascript) not being rendered in the PDF. I am looking for a way to delay the conversion until the document is ready and have not yet found a way to do this. Currently I am using the following to convert my html doc:

```
var converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter {PageFooterHtml = "<div>Page: <span class='page'></span><div>", Margins = new PageMargins() {
                Bottom = 10,
     }, CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--print-media-type"
     };
     var pdfBytes = converter.GeneratePdfFromFile(url, null);
```

the javascript on my html page which is not being rendered in the pdf looks like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ..javascript which changes my html
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wkhtmltopdf default delay for javascript execution is 200ms; it can be easily increased in the following way:

```
var pdfGen = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
pdfGen.CustomWkHtmlArgs = " --javascript-delay 1000 ";   // 1 sec delay for js execution
```

Note that you can use another approach to ensure that js code is executed: wkhtmltopdf can wait for some specific window.status value. For example, you can change window.status when barcode rendering is finished:

```
window.status = "READY";
```

and say wkhtmltopdf to wait for this status:

```
pdfGen.CustomWkHtmlArgs = " --window-status READY ";
```

Comment: perfect. Just curious where you found to use that string `--javascript-delay 1000` I looked over the documentation very well and do not see anything listed out for what I can pass into `CustomWkHtmlArgs`

Comment: @peggy you can get complete list of available options by running "wkhtmltopdf --help"

Comment: Hi I am using NReco.PdfGenerator.dll. I have observed that wkhtmltopdf.exe, msvcp120.dll, msvcr.dll creates outside bin in root directory. anyone experienced the same?

Comment: @ShekharDalvi PdfGenerator extracts wkhtmltopdf binaries on first use; you can change the location of these files with 'PdfToolPath' property.